# How to select one of n objects at random without knowing n at first?

Tags: c, algorithm

For concreteness, how would you read text line, and select and print one random line, when you don't know the number of lines in advance?

Yes this is a problem from the programming pearl which I get confused.

The solution choose the 1st element, then select the second with probability 1/2, the third with 1/3, and so forth.

An algorithm:

```
i = 0
while more input lines
  with probability 1.0/++i
    choice = this input line
 print choice
```

Suppose the final choice is the 3rd element, the probability is 
1 x 1/2 x **1/3** x 3/4 x ... x n-2/n-1 x n-1/n == 1/2n ? But 1/n should be correct.

Comment: The probability that element 3 is chosen does not depend at all on what was chosen at step 1 or 2. So, you do not include the 1 or 1/2 terms here. Then it's 1/n.

Comment: cool question, never thought about that!

Comment: Actually, there is a a lot such interesting problems in <<Programming Pearls>> by Jon Bentley :)

Comment: Is print within the while loop? it seems to have an initial indent of one space which looks as if it could, in fact, be an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your algorithm is correct, but the analysis is not. You can prove it by induction. Loosely: It works for N = 1 of course. If it works up to N-1, then what happens at N? The chance that the Nth element is chosen and overwrites the last choice is 1/N -- good. The chance that it isn't is (N-1)/N. In which case the choice from the previous step is used. But at that point all elements had an 1/(N-1) chance of being chosen. Now it's 1/N. Good.

Answer (score 1):

**Your calculation is wrong :**

*Suppose the final choice is the 3rd element, the probability is 
1 x 1/2 x 1/3 x 3/4 x ... x n-2/n-1 x n-1/n*

**The real probability is :**

(1 x 1/2 + 1 x 1/2)  x 1/3 x 3/4 x ... x n-2/n-1 x n-1/n  == 1/n

since either you chose 2 or you don't chose 2 (chosing 2 has a proba of 1/2 and not chosing 2 a proba of 1/2)

Answer (score 0):

Read 1
Read 2
50 % chance of either, keep one, discard one.
Read 3
(we should have either 1 and 3 or 2 and 3).
50% chance of either of the lines, discard the other.
Keep working with a 50% chance all the way through the file, this leaves you with 2 lines.
Take a 50/50 on either of the lines and you have a random line.
The odds were even for the whole file.

Comment: Are you implying with your last sentence that the probability of being chosen is the same for every line in the file with this algorithm? Because that wouldn't be the case. The actual probability distribution would be exponential.

Answer (score -1):

This is not truely random - as you are more likely to chose a line at the start of the file. You need to know the number of lines to make it random. (50% of the time you get the first line!)

Comment: it is random. the fact that it is not [Uniform distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29), doesn't make it not random.

Comment: Note that the algorithm does not *return* if a line is chosen. It just becomes the current choice. It does work.

Comment: @sean - You are correct. But in that case the choice will not be unifom. It will be higher towards the end of the file.

Comment: I don't think so -- see the inductive argument above. This is a known 'programming pearl'. You do not get the first line 50% of the time. You get it 100% of the time if there is 1 line. If there's a 2nd line, it's kept with probability 1/2 (2nd line doesn't replace it). And at line 3, it survives again with chance 2/3 (3rd line doesn't replace it).